# R Keras concatenate two neural network

Tags: r, neural-network, keras, lstm

I need to concatenate two neural networks, as shown in Figure bellow. But, I get the following error message:

> Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument

***How can I concatenate the two networks?***

*Source code:*

```
layer1 <- layer_input(shape = c(MAX), dtype = "int32")
output_tensor <- layer1 %>%
    layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu")
```

[image: Framework example]

Comment: As a start, try changing "int32" to "float32".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
library(keras)

max_words <- 20
nb_words <- 1000

text_one_hot <- layer_input(nb_words)
text_as_int <- layer_input(max_words)

vec_1 <- text_one_hot %>%
  layer_dense(100)

vec_2 <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = nb_words, output_dim = 128, 
  input_length = max_words
  ) %>%
  layer_lstm(128)

out <- layer_concatenate(list(vect_1, vec_2))

model <- keras_model(list(input_1, input_2))
```

[This link](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/keras-duplicate-questions-quora.html) has a similar example.